# Pass in a callback function to a template in the router

Tags: javascript, angular

In the following code, passing in `showDialogFunc` doesn't work, and I cannot see it get called from the child. I'm fairly new to Angular and I guess I'm doing something, very basic, wrong.

```
/*
 * @ngInject
 */
export default function($stateProvider: StateProvider: void {
    let _showDialog = false;

    $stateProvider.state('manage.user', {
        url: '/manageuser',
        template: '<manage-user (showDialogFunc)="showDialogFunc"></manage-user>',
        reloadOnSearch: false
    })

    function showDialogFunc() {
        this._showDialog = true;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'manage-user',
    templateUrl: 'manage-user.component.html'
})
export class ManageUserComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    @Output() readonly showDialogFunc: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if(//....) {
            this.showDialogFunc.emit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `(showDialogFun)`, you define an event. So your line should read like an action to perform (here a function to call) -- not like an object:

```
(showDialogFunc)="showDialogFunc()"
```

As opposed to if you want to pass a function *object* from a parent component to a child component where you would have:

```
<child-component [function_object]="showDialogFunc">...
```

and in the child component code:

```js
@Input() function_object: () => number;
// ...
my_function() {
  // Call the function given by the parent
  this.function_object();
}
```

Comment: It's still undefined. `showDialogFunc` in the parent component isn't referenced (I can  verify this in intellij, too).

Comment: Just realized when paying attention to your weird `function`, I thought it was a component. I don't know angularjs, can only talk of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the function

```
(showDialogFunc)="showDialogFunc()"
```

Note the () braces at the end of the function name.